# problem when using javascript to display banner, the banner does not display when using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am newbie with javascript and here is my problem.

Here is my code

```
https://codepen.io/nguyencuc2035/pen/XWVXxxK
```

As you can see in my code, I wrote a javascript to display a banner named toast at a right conner and here is the code

```
<script>
        function toast({
            title = '',
            message = '',
            type = 'info',
            duration = 3000
        }) {
            const main = documet.getElementById('toast');
            if (main) {
                const toast = documet.createElement('div');
                toast.classList.add('toast');
                toast.innerHTML = `
                <div class="toast__icon">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="toast__body">
                <h3 class="toast__title">Success</h3>
                <p class="toast__msg">Import an external stylesheet:</p>
                </div>
                <div class="toast__close">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i>
                </div>
                `;
                main.appendChild(toast);
            }
        }
        toast({
            title: 'Success',
            message: 'Import an external stylesheet:',
            type: 'success',
            duration: 3000
        })
    </script>
```

Of course in the styles.css I wrote .toast .toast__icon , .toast__body , .toast__close,

But my problem is, when I ran my code, it only display the toast__body and toast__close, not display the toast.

Could you please give me some advice for this problem ? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: what happens instead? is there an error in the browser console?

Comment: `documet` should be `document`.

Comment: @jkoch - would've been nicer to let the OP do some basic debugging and discover his typo himself :p

Answer (score 0):

I Fidgeted with your code on Codepen, and it seems you've used `documet` **and not** `document`. You're missing an N.

Remember you have to be really careful with your spellings in JavaScript. If it still doesn't work feel free to reply back. Hope this helped.

And if it helps you can use [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) to just append the banner. It really simplifies the code as well.

Comment: thank you for your help. Your comment are so great. But when I coded, the visual studio did not automatically repair my mistake, could you please advice me some tools or some extensions to autorepair this kind of mistake ?

Comment: Yes, there are many extension You can use. I'm pasting a link below, which will help you with intellisense: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/extensions